# Does this series converge ? $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^n(\sqrt[n]{a}-1), a \geq 1$ Hint: $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\sqrt[n]{a}-1}{1/n} = \ln{a}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence, summation

Does this series converge ?
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^n(\sqrt[n]{a}-1), a \geq 1$$

Hint: use the fact that
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\sqrt[n]{a}-1}{1/n} = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{a^h-1}{h} = \ln{a}$$

---

My first idea was to use the alternating series test.
The non-alternating part is $b_n = \sqrt[n]{a}-1$. It is monotonically decreasing
because as $n \to \infty$, the term $\sqrt[n]{a}$ will decrease. Also, $b_n$ approaches $0$ because $b_n = \sqrt[n]{a}-1$ and $\sqrt[n]{a}$ approaches $1$ for $n \to \infty$, so $\sqrt[n]{a}-1$ will tend to $0$.

First, is this correct ?

Second, if this is really correct, I don't think I used their hints at all. Do you have an idea how to solve this using the hint ?

Comment: The hint is to prove that $\sqrt[n]{a}-1$ approaches $0$, I guess. though it's not necessary, as you pointed out